# How to restructure the JSON Object with existing key values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I need to restructure the JSON object with existing key values, please check below input format of JSON

```
{
  'Demo-1': [
    {
      sku: 'Brisk',
      count: '2',
    },
    {
      sku: 'Pepsi Cans',
      count: '2',
    },
    {
      sku: 'Pepsi Cans',
      count: '4',
    }
    
  ],
  
  'Demo-2' :{
    "A":[
        {
        sku: 'Mountain',
        count: '4',
        },
        {
        sku: 'Pepsi Bottles',
        count: '4',
        }
    ],
    "B":[
        {
        sku: 'Lipton Dietgreentea',
        count: '2',
        },
        {
        sku: 'Lipton Dietgreentea Mixedberry',
        count: '2',
        }
 
    ]
  }
}
```

In the above input JSON, the "Demo-1" have a single array of object and the second one has two array object.
I would like to change the above array, into like below
**Result**

```
{
    'Demo-1': {
        items: [{
                sku: 'Brisk',
                count: '2',
            },
            {
                sku: 'Pepsi',
                count: '2',
            },
            {
                sku: 'Pepsi',
                count: '4',
            }

        ],
        mode: "Veri",
        istatus: "open"

    },
    'Demo-2': {
        "items":{ 
           "A" :[
               {
                    sku: 'Mountain',
                    count: '4',
                },
                {
                    sku: 'Pepsi Bottles',
                    count: '4',
                }
            ],
            "B" :[ 
            {
                sku: 'Lipton Dietgreentea',
                count: '2',
            },
            {
                sku: 'Lipton Dietgreentea Mixedberry',
                count: '2',
            }]
        },
        mode: "Doubled",
        istatus: "Closed"
    }
}
```

I already using below code solution for partially achiving this

```
Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).map(
      ([key, items]) => [key, { items, mode: "verification", status: "open" }]
    )
  )
```

Now if the object has two array objects like Demo-2, the mode value should be "Doubled"
please help me out in resolving this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add condition into your mapping function.
Proper condition depends on what possible `items` values may be.
If `items` *always* either `array` or `{ A, B } object`, following condition is enough:

```js
Object.fromEntries(
 Object.entries(obj).map(
   ([key, items]) => [key, { items, mode: Array.isArray(items) ? 'Single' : 'Doubled', status: 'open' }]
 )
)
```